# how to hide and show sidenavbar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**javascript**
as see in the js code I m trying the method but I'm struggling to do it js code is not working as well smoothly what I want to write this code and run I m so stuck lots of time to try

```
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var sidenav = document.getElementById('sidenav');
    sidenav.style.right = "-300px";

    menu.onclick = function () {
        if (sidenav.style.right = "-300px")
            sidenav.style.right = "0px"
    }

    else {
        sidenav.style.right = "-300px"
    }`enter code here`
```

Comment: you make code more complex, I would use `classList.toggle()` instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` instead of `=`, and the else need to be inside the function

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var sidenav = document.getElementById('sidenav');
sidenav.style.right = "-300px";

menu.onclick = function () {
    if (sidenav.style.right == "-300px")
        sidenav.style.right = "0px"
    else
        sidenav.style.right = "-300px"
}
```

When you use `=` you change the variable at the left term to the value of the right term, when you use `==` you check if the terms at each side are equals.

Answer (score 1):

First off, whatever element you want to move needs to have a css position attribute. For example

```
#sidenav {
  position: relative
}
```

Also here is a rewrite of your code

```
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var sidenav = document.getElementById('sidenav');
    sidenav.style.right = "-300px";

    menu.onclick = function () {
        if (sidenav.style.right == "-300px") {
            sidenav.style.right = "0px"
    }

    else {
        sidenav.style.right = "-300px"
    }
```

Note the curly brace that was in front of your if statement